# Why does `require` work locally but not in CI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, github-actions

I am trying to use jest.axe in my very basic react app (created by create-react-app). Locally, this passes just fine with `yarn test`

```
const {axe, toHaveNoViolations} = require('jest-axe')
expect.extend(toHaveNoViolations)
... 
const {container} = render(<App/>)
const results = await axe(container)
expect(results).toHaveNoViolations()
```

However, in my github actions pipeline I get the following error

```
    Cannot find module 'jest-axe' from 'src/App.test.tsx'

  3 | import App from './App';
  4 |
> 5 | const {axe, toHaveNoViolations} = require('jest-axe')
```

**Actions File**

```
name: Run Unit Tests
on: [push]
jobs:
  Run-Unit-Tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - name: Run tests
        id: run-tests
        run: CI=true yarn test
```

My yarn.lock file has jest.axe.

I tried `import { axe, toHaveNoViolations } from "jest-axe";` in my test file but then it fails locally :/

Comment: what about `import * as axe from "jest-axe"`?

Comment: Sadly not. I have a line in my test `expect.extend(toHaveNoViolations)` which will error out if I use the *

Comment: so if you do that then you should use the `axe` methods with `.` notation like `axe.toHaveNoViolations`

Comment: Start investigating by comparing environments. Which Node versions are in each environment?

Comment: @Heartbit - no sadly not. Get "    Cannot find module 'jest-axe' from 'src/App.test.tsx" when I try to run the test locally

Comment: try to remove your `node_modules` then install all packages again by `yarn ` or `npm install`